# How can I move a resource (service or app) between spaces or Orgs?

Tags: ibm-cloud

Is it possible to move a service from one space to another? And between orgs?

For example, I have an instance of the Alchemy Service (which is deprecated so I cannot create a new instance of the service), and I need to move it to a different space.

Comment: Is this the same as stackoverflow.com/questions/45239288/… or stackoverflow.com/questions/45452249/...

Comment: No, I am talking about services not apps... I can't create a new instance of the service in an existing space. I need to be able to move it...

Comment: No - I don't know of a way to "pick up and move" a service from one space to another.

Comment: I know that you want to keep your deprecated service instance. However, you will need to migrate before March 7th any way. You can migrate from AlchemyAPI to either Watson Discovery or Watson Natural Language to have less expensive pricing options. See: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/03/bye-bye-alchemyapi/